# Is there software that simulates the Tri-D or 3-D chess as seen in Star Trek?

Tags: engines, chess-variants, software

I want to try [this game](http://www.chessvariants.org/3d.dir/startrek.html) without making/buying a board and it is easier to learn to play when the computer can prevent invalid moves. Does any software, preferably freeware, exist which simulates this flavor of chess?

Comment: I had some manner of Star Trek book when I was a kid.  Back then, there was only the 60's show. The book covered many 'behind the scenes' sort of topics. Once was 3-D chess.  I would like to mention the game was simply made up - no play testing, nothing. It's just a prop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> There is software for playing Tri-D Chess; Parmen is a Windows application written by Doug Keenan and available free on his website.

Here are some of the external links for (software) Raumschach and Tri-D chess:

> http://www.pathguy.com/chess/Chess3D.htm
>
> http://www.cosmicchess.com/
>
> http://www.parmen.com/

There is a version available for Android:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=awfsoft.app.TriDChess

Comment: Parmen keeps crashing.
Cosmic chess site is no longer active. The domain is for sale.

Comment: I haven't had problems with Parmen crashing.